# using linux auto tools

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux

I am a windows xp (SP3)user and new to linux utilities.
I need to use autoconf, and other auto tools from linux.I have the following installed in my system.

-Msys version 1.0.11
       -msysDTK-1.0.1
       -msysgit
       -wget-1.11.4-1
       -autoconf-2.68
       -automake-1.11.1
       -libtool-2.4.1
       -libcrypt-1.1
       -perl-5.8.8
       -m4-1.4.14
       -gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32
       -glib_2.28.1-1_win32
       -glib_2.28.8-1_win32
       -pkg-config_0.23-3_win32
       -pkg-config-dev_0.23-3_win32

I tried the tutorial "Introduction to autotools" from the **http://www.dwheeler.com/autotools**
Configure.ac was created with the following lines,

```
AC_INIT([hello], [0.01])
AC_OUTPUT
```

From the Msys shell, ran the command

```
$ autoreconf -i
```

I got the following log,

```
/usr/share/aclocal/autoopts.m4:22: warning: underquoted definition of AG_PATH_AU
TOOPTS
/usr/share/aclocal/autoopts.m4:22:   run info '(automake)Extending aclocal'
/usr/share/aclocal/autoopts.m4:22:   or see http://sources.redhat.com/automake/a
utomake.html#Extending-aclocal
```

I previously tried another archived tutorial from the net, i.e.,
with a directory called hello-initial. The 'hello-initial' has a src directory containing  hello.c and hello.h. 
I created Makefile.am with the following line:

SUBDIRS=src.

Within the src directory, created Makefile.am with the following lines,

```
helloprgdir=../
helloprg_PROGRAMS=hello
hello_SOURCES=hello.c
```

I cd ed to the hello-initial directory in the msys shell, and followed the tutorial, and the following log was produced namely,

```
Raji@COMPUTER_1 ~
$ cd /gold/hello-initial

Raji@COMPUTER_1 /gold/hello-initial
$ autoscan

Raji@COMPUTER_1 /gold/hello-initial
$ aclocal
/usr/share/aclocal/autoopts.m4:22: warning: underquoted definition of AG_PATH_AU
TOOPTS
/usr/share/aclocal/autoopts.m4:22:   run info '(automake)Extending aclocal'
/usr/share/aclocal/autoopts.m4:22:   or see http://sources.redhat.com/automake/a
utomake.html#Extending-aclocal
configure.ac:8: warning: macro `AM_CONFIG_HEADERS' not found in library

Raji@COMPUTER_1 /gold/hello-initial
$ automake -ac
configure.ac:7: installing `./install-sh'
configure.ac:7: installing `./missing'
automake: no `Makefile.am' found for any configure output.
```

---

Pl help.
Rgds,

Comment: Please, do yourself and the world a favor and do not use autotools.  Use, for example, CMake instead.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a switch to CMake. Autotools are more like autohell. Unless, of course, you're forced to use them (e.g. contributing to the Gnome platform)...

Answer (score 1):

configure.ac

```
AC_INIT([project name], [major.minor.revision], [bugreport@bar.xx])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])dnl foreign means that its not standard gnu project or not strict
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Autoconf language is 'm4' check for that in autoconf info pages.
Info pages of automake are good place to start.
http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/ for geting docs and autoconf itself
For installing autotools use
'autoreconf --install'
and for updating autoconf 
'autoreconf' or 'autoconf'